# has_and_belongs_to_many assocation is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, associations

I have a problem with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association in my Ruby On Rails project.

Here are my models:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :city, :map_url, :name, :uimage_url
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :furnitures_id
end

class Furniture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image_url, :maintenance, :name, :size
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :store_id
end
```

This is my join table migration:

```
create_table "furnitures_stores", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "furniture_id"
  t.integer "store_id"
end
```

I then tried to insert some values with seed.rb:

```
Furniture.delete_all
furnitures =  Furniture.create([{name: 'aaaa 1'}])

Store.delete_all
storee =  Store.create([{name: 'S 1'}])
```

But it doesn't work; I have this error:

```
**rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Store::FurnituresId**
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `has_and_belongs_to_many :furnitures` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :stores`. You need to refer to the model, not the foreign key.

See [A Guide to ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) for more information.

Comment: but how can I refer to model?

Comment: @Teo I don't know what you mean.